# "Have you seen James's Guitar? " Where's the error here?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, articles, error

I failed to find mistake in the following sentences:

**Have you seen James's Guitar?**

I found this as an MCQ in a book. but I didn't get any explanation of the mistakes. Kindly help me to find the error.

Comment: Is 'unnecessary and non-standard' the same as 'a mistake'? And James's Guitar could be the name of a movie.

Comment: I've reduced it to one question.  Now, please edit to add 1) the name of the book. 2) any thoughts you've had.  I can see two very minor things that some (not all) people might call errors, so please check that you have copied the example exactly as printed.

Comment: MCQ= multiple choice question?  What were the options?

Answer (score 1):

The only error is the capital letter on "Guitar".  The word "guitar" is not a proper noun, so not capitalised. (Unless, as in a comment *James's Guitar* is the name of a movie.)

Some people would also spell the possessive of "James" as " James’ ".  But actual use varies. For example, there is "St James's Park" in London, but "St James' Park" in Tyneside.

Comment: In Canada, I was taught that the possessive form of a proper noun ending in `s` is to add the apostrophe without the trailing `s`. This grammatical rule is strictly followed in North America, at least to my 4+ decades of observation. As for St. James's Park in London, I can only note that there is also an Alligator Park (near Alligator Creek) in Australia, a nation in which there exist only crocodiles.

Comment: As a James,  I consider James'  to be as wrong as "the compass' needle"  But I'm grown up enough not to fret over it.  Some people do write James' and some (including me) do write James's   There is variation in use, and "St James's Park" is doubtlessly correct, and the only only proper spelling of the name of the park in London.

Comment: (TIC) Not to worry, it's prolly one of the many things ye Brits got wrong when inventing English v1.0. Fortunately, we over here in the land of English 2.0 have made many improvements, not the least of which was not adopting Cockney rhyming slang. *Fixing the `s's` was one of the more minor improvements, along with pronouncing `ma'am` as `ma'am` not `marm`.*

Comment: Blimey,  wot a septic. An' no mistake